# "more sign up options" link is covered up on Spanish site

Tags: bug, design, internationalization, sign-up

The Spanish translation for "more sign up options" shown on the signup page is "más opciones para registrarse" which longer than English or Portuguese translations and it is partially covered up by the "Register" button.

[image: http://imgur.com/XeGTxbS.png]

Ideally the text should wrap to the next line or be displayed on a separate line. One way to easily achieve this for most browsers would be to use flexbox on the container and set the link to have a flex value of `1`.

Additionally the padding is not ideal for the "Register" button. It looks as though padding was partially used to center the text on the English site but makes the text off-centered on the Spanish site.

The same problem also exists on the Portuguese site:

[image]

Comment: You should probably post this on meta.es.SE: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Maybe but I don't speak Spanish and the problem need to be fixed in the common code-base (at at least I would hope it would be).

Comment: @Godwin You don't speak Spanish... then how did you end up there?

Comment: @TJ, I also don't sign up for new accounts but I don't see why that should prevent me from speaking up for the users that do. I ended up there because I was curious on how other sites had solved a particular i18n issue that I had come across.

Comment: @JAL According to [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252392/323179) you can add the internationalization tag (as I just did) and they will find it. Of course, posting on the localized meta would be better, but only for those who feel comfortable doing so.